# Speeding up a linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to replicate the following SQL query with linq. On SQL Server it takes a fraction of a second to run:

```
select g.reference, count(*)
from isis.dbo.[group] as g inner join
     isis.dbo.enrolment as e on g.groupid = e.groupid inner join
     isis.dbo.student as s on e.studentid = s.studentid inner join
     isis.dbo.progression as p on s.studentid = p.studentid
where p.academicyear = '12/13' and g.istutorgroup = 1 
group by reference
```

In my MVC application I am passing a listing of "TutorGroups" to the view. For each tutor group in the view I need to display various information about them, one item being the number of "Progression" interviews they have had.

I have tried a couple of methods but they both take upwards of 30 secs to run in my MVC application:

```
<%TTMrequired = tg.Enrolments
                  .SelectMany(e => e.Student.Progressions
                                    .Where(p => p.TTMChecked == false && 
                                                p.TTMInterview == true && 
                                                p.AcademicYear == year))
                  .Count(); %>
```

and

```
<%TTMrequired = tg.Enrolments
                  .Where(e => e.Student.Progressions
                               .Any(p => p.TTMChecked == false && 
                                         p.TTMInterview == true && 
                                         p.AcademicYear == year))
                  .Count(); %>
```

Anyone got any suggestions on how I can speed this up? I suspect the problem is me trying to do it a stupid way - it usually is!

Comment: How are those statements related? The SQL version queries a `group` table and groups by its reference. I can't find anything similar in your LINQ versions.

Comment: Sorry I should have given more detail - I have edited my question to include details. The view has a list of "Tutor Groups" passed to it, and a foreach loop goes through each of them working out the number of "Progression" interviews the students have had for that group.

Comment: If this is an MVC application, why are you doing this in the V? It should be part of the model. What are you trying to achieve with this query? Stepping back to the problem may help to isolate a better solution. In particular, I'm questioning the grouping/count for what appears to be a "required" flag. Also, use a profiler to make sure you're not calling this inside a loop (binding in a grid for example).

Comment: @Chris, looks like you're hitting an n+1 issue. Refactoring the model to include the count in the original query would probably be best.

Comment: I am calling this inside a loop, so I think you are right - I will need to change my model so that it is calculated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a `Sum` of counts instead of a `SelectMany`:

```
tg.Enrolments.Sum(e => e.Student.Progressions
                                .Count(p => p.TTMChecked == false && 
                                            p.TTMInterview == true && 
                                            p.AcademicYear == year)
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried it but it takes the same amount of time unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Should be written using this syntax:

```
var TTMRequired = (from g in tg.Groups 
                   join e in tg.Enrolment on g.groupid equals e.groupid
                   join s in tg.Students on e.studentid equals s.studentid
                   join p in tg.Progressions on s.studentid = p.studentid
                   where p.academicyear.Equals("12/13") && g.istutorgroup.Equals(1)
                   group g by g.reference into grp
                   select new { 
                      grpRef = grp.Key,
                      grpCount = grp.Count()
                   });
```

Note: if `g.istutorgroup` is of type `BIT` instead of `INT`, consider using `.Equals(true)`.

Comment: I based my answer on your original SQL query.